# Dropdown list colour based on selection from multiple ranges

Tags: excel, excel-formula, google-sheets

I've been trying to make this work in google spreadsheets and I'm not sure where the differences between that and excel are, so I just tagged both.

Here's what I'm trying to do:
I have multiple dropdown lists that choose from a range of different words on sheet2.
I want each cell with the dropdown to be coloured based on what option is chosen.

```
If the chosen option is "wordA or wordD or wordB" > blue
If the chosen option is "wordF or wordC or wordE" > green
etc.
```

At first I tried to colourize each option in sheet2 in the colour I want but that didn't work, probably too easy that way.
What I know is that I need a conditional format for it and I could make a rule for each individual word to be coloured the way I want. The problem there is that with the amount of words you can choose from that would take quite some time, though I'd probably be done by now I'd done that instead of trying to figure out how to do it the smart way, which I think would be a formula that checks if a word is part of range 1 (blue), 2 (green) or 3 (red) and colours the cell with the dropdown accordingly.

I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering you could arrange the words like below by grouping them by the format you need `1-Red` `2-Blue` `3-Green`

```
A        B   ..       G
WordA    1            1
WordB    1
WordD    2             WordA
WordC    1
WordE    2
WordF    2
.
.
```

Create a new cell(`G1`) whose value would be based on the drop down value
 chosen(`G3`)  as below..

```
= VLOOKUP(G3,A:B,2,0)
```

Now you can apply conditional formatting based on the value in cell `G1`.

Comment: You can put the extra Column B and G1 where they will not interfere with the current structure you have. Also for googlespreadsheet you need to use `;` as the separator in the formula I think.

Answer (score 0):

You could simplify Conditional Formatting using the BETWEEN rules for the entire group of letters (instead of individual letters), like (as per your original example): `BETWEEN A and C -> format Blue`, and so on. Likewise, you can apply it to the new set of words in your edited question (i.e. BETWEEN wordA and wordC, etc), and also to numeric values as well. In case of more complex (non-sequential set of words) either use `IF()`, `OR()` or `AND()` Excel Worksheet formulas for grouping, or create a custom VBA function.

The example of using `OR()` function follows. Enter all non-sequential words in some column (for certainty, let it be Column `AA`)

```
AA
WordHello   (should be blue)
HiEverybody (should be blue)
HiFolks     (should be blue)
DearSir     (should be green)
DearMadam   (should be green)
HeyDude     (should be green)
```

Then, in the target cells, for example `A1` enter the Conditional Formatting Formula: `=OR(A1=$AA$1, A1=$AA$2, A1=$AA$3)` and specify color `Blue`. The same technique apply to other groups.

Hope this may help.

Comment: I meant for the letters to be placeholders for words. I rephrased that part of the question, hopefully it's more clear now.

Comment: It will work on that set of words as well - see my extended answer.

Comment: Another edit, what would an IF() formula look like in that case?

Comment: Please see the extended answer and accept if satisfied. If you have more questions/edits, please post them separately. Thanks and regards,